# xpath to select all leaf nodes with given ancestors attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a batch of xmls where each tag has an attribute isOptional. An example of such xml is

```
<node1 isOptional="False">
    <node2 isOptional="True">
        <node22 isOptional="False">
            <node3 isOptional="False">text4</node3>
        </node22>
    </node2>
    <node4 isOptional="False">
        <node5 isOptional="False">
            <node6 isOptional="True">text3</node6>
            <node7 isOptional="False">
                <node8 isOptional="True">text2</node8>
                <node9 isOptional="False">text1</node9>
            </node7>
        </node5>
    </node4>
</node1>
```

I need to write xpath to select all leaf nodes which do not have ancessors with `@isOptional="True"`. For this example the result should be:

```
       <node9 isOptional="False">text1</node9>
```

Actually I need something like this:

```
//*[not(*) and @isOptional="False" and count(ancestor::*[@isOptional = "True"] = 0)]
```

Could you please help me to get the correct xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XPath like this one should work:

```
//*[not(child::*) and not(ancestor-or-self::*[@isOptional = 'True'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to mention one additional requirement. What you said:

> I need to write xpath to select all leaf nodes which do not have ancessors with `@isOptional="True"`

would map to the following XPath expression:

```
//*[not(*) and not(ancestor::*[@isOptional = 'True'])]
^^^                                                           "all"
   ^^^^^^^                                                    "leaf nodes"
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        "no ancestor where
                                                              @isOptional equals 'True'"
```

which would yield (individual results separated by `------`):

```
<node6 isOptional="True">text3</node6>
-----------------------
<node8 isOptional="True">text2</node8>
-----------------------
<node9 isOptional="False">text1</node9>
```

But I assume you meant to add: Additionally, the `isOptional` attribute of the target nodes must not be set to `True` either. This results in the following path expression, already correctly suggested by potame:

```
//*[not(*) and not(ancestor-or-self::*[@isOptional = 'True'])]
```

and the only result is

```
<node9 isOptional="False">text1</node9>
```

because now the XPath expression contains the `ancestor-or-self::` axis, which includes the context node itself.